# Why is the solution to this differential equation only defined between its quadratic roots?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

One of my homework problems (from Boyce's Introduction to Differential Equations) is as follows:

$y' = (1-2x)y^2$, $y(0) = -\frac{1}{6}$; find the explicit form of the solution to this initial value problem and determine the interval in which the solution is defined.

Solving it is easy enough.

$$y^{-2}*y' = 1 - 2x$$
$$\int y^{-2}dy = \int (1 - 2x)dx$$
$$-y^{-1} = x-x^2+c$$
$$y = -(x-x^2+c)^{-1}$$
$$y = \frac{1}{x^2-x+c}$$

Plugging in the initial value: $y(0)=-\frac{1}{6}$:

$$-\frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{0^2-0+c} = \frac{1}{c}$$
$$c = -6$$

Therefore the explicit solution is:

$$y(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 - x - 6}$$

What's troubling me is the interval in which the solution is supposedly defined. The book gives the answer as being $(-2,3)$ which seems to come from the roots of the polynomial in the fraction:

$$x^2-x-6 \ne 0$$
$$(x-3)(x+2) \ne 0$$
$$x \ne 3,-2$$

But why does is the solution only defined **between** these two roots? If you plug in say, $x = 4$, then $y(x)$ becomes

$$y(4) = \frac{1}{16-4-6} = \frac{1}{6}$$

So it seems as though $y(x)$ *is* defined outside of $(-2,3)$. What am I overlooking?

Comment: This is a difference between the *expression* which defines the solution and the solution itself. By definition any solution to an ODE has an interval (possibly an infinite one) as its domain.

Comment: Probably doesn't want to cause any worry about those undefined points, so the book simply stays inside them to avoid such problems.

Comment: Don't you want to consider only the intervals that contain the initial condition?

Comment: If you define a piecewise function with different values of c on the outside intervals, those would also be solutions.

Comment: LouisB, thank you, that is correct. I completely forgot about the condition that the interval contain the initial condition. Thanks a bunch.